# How to create multiple temporary tables in one cell in Jupyter?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, jupyter-notebook, azure-hdinsight

I am using Spark 2.1 on Azure (HDInsight) with Jupyter notebook.

I can't create multiple tables in one notebook cell.

The following query works fine:

```
%%sql

create table if not exists temp1(Col varchar(32))
```

returns: No results.

[image: Result]

The following queries do not work in a single cell:

```
%%sql

create table if not exists temp2(Col varchar(32))
create table if not exists temp3(Col varchar(32))
```

[image]

> An error was encountered:
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException: mismatched input
>   'create' expecting (line 3, pos 0)
>
> == SQL ==
>
> create table if not exists temp2(Col varchar(32)) create table if not
>   exists temp3(Col varchar(32)) ^^^
>
> at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException.withCommand(ParseDriver.scala:197)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AbstractSqlParser.parse(ParseDriver.scala:99)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkSqlParser.parse(SparkSqlParser.scala:45)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AbstractSqlParser.parsePlan(ParseDriver.scala:53)
>   at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sql(SparkSession.scala:592)   ...
>   47 elided

How can I create multiple tables in one cell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It *appears* that a single cell in Jupyter with `sql` interpreter corresponds to a single SQL query that Spark executes.

A possible workaround could be to use `spark` interpreter (or `scala`) and execute the SQL statements inside `spark.sql` as follows:

```
%%spark

spark.sql("create table if not exists temp2(Col varchar(32))")
spark.sql("create table if not exists temp3(Col varchar(32))")
```

That is *supposed* to work.

Comment: Don't think so given the stack trace from `AbstractSqlParser` that is executed after `SparkSession.sql`. In other words, can you execute two complete SQL statements using `sql` operator? Or perhaps Jupyter parses `;` specially??? Dunno.

Comment: I don't think so. `spark-sql` shell is not bothered by multiple statements in a single line though, so it shouldn't be a hard limitation. Anyway, just fishing here. I don't know how `%%sql` magic is implemented.

Comment: Right. `spark-sql` works fine with `;` even on a single line.

Comment: @zero323 adding `;` gives `An error was encountered:
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException:
mismatched input ';' expecting <EOF>`

Comment: @JacekLaskowski 


`spark.sql("create table if not exists temp2(Col varchar(32));
create table if not exists temp3(Col varchar(32))")`


doesn't work